# Synchronous Service call in SAP CAPM : HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cap

I am trying to make synchronous service call from a SAP CAPM service via a Destination. I am using `service.send` method to make synchronous service calls. The request gets executed fine when a single request is processed but when I try to call the same in a loop inside a Promise the request fails:

> HTTP 500 Error

Code:

[image]

Error details:

[image]

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.